# Out of Memory in ngFor

Tags: angular

I have an angular application. And I have below code I tried.

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="year>0 && month>0">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="">Organization</th>
                        <th *ngFor="let pos of positions">{{pos.POSITION}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let org of orgs">
                        <td>{{org.ORG_NAME}}</td>
                        <td *ngFor="let pos of positions">
                            <div *ngFor="let el of budget">
                                <div *ngIf="el.ORG_ID==org.ORG_ID && el.POS_ID==pos.ID">
                                    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="el.AMOUNT" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code above I am trying to  create a dynamic table from arrays

org like

`[{ORG_ID:1,ORG_NAME:"TEST"}]` and have 114 elements inside

pos like

`[{ID:1,POSITION:"TEST"}]` and 16 elements inside

and budget like

`[{POS_ID:1,ORG_ID:9,AMOUNT:5}]` and have 1824 elements inside. I want to create a pos orgs table and put input elements that match with the budget element. But when I run the page It gives an error page with Out of Memory.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You try to render 3,326,976 inputs, this is way too much. You need to use something like virtual scroll to render only row that are visible. `@angular/cdk` have an implementation: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

Comment: but there will be only 144 rows and 16 columns  and input inside them.

Comment: You loop orgs then positions then budget, so you have 114 * 16 * 1824 = 3,326,976 inputs. It's just too much to handle. Can you show only one org or one position at a time? That should be doable. Otherwise, you'll have to use virtual scroll.

Comment: My bad, you filter the budget with an ngIf, so you don't actually have that much input, but you have that much div. Try changing `<div *ngFor="let el of budget">` to `<ng-container *ngFor="let el of budget">`

Comment: I tried ng-conrainer but no worked

Comment: You should try to reduce the number of iteration. Maybe loop the budget array to create a new one with [{POS_ID:1,ORG_ID:9,AMOUNT:5, POS: {...}, ORG: {...}}]. Then In the template you can *ngFor over this new array only. No more nested loop.
Edit: Well, not exactly this, since you need to display your positions column but you get the idea.

Comment: 3,326,976 inputs is way too many elements to render. Also I'd say he needs to do the filtering and mapping before he event attempts to render the data, in essence this should be a single loop. Also doing things beforehand should improve performance as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pipe filter on your budget's loop instead of ngIf directive :

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="year>0 && month>0">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="">Organization</th>
                        <th *ngFor="let pos of positions">{{pos.POSITION}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let org of orgs">
                        <td>{{org.ORG_NAME}}</td>
                        <td *ngFor="let pos of positions">
                            <ng-container*ngFor="let el of budget | filterBudget: pos.ID : org.ORG_ID">
                                <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="el.AMOUNT" />
                            </ng-container>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

filterBudgetPipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterBudget'
})
export class FilterBudgetPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(budgets: Budget[], posId: number, orgId: number):  Budget[] {
    return budgets.filter(budget => budget.ID === posId && budget.ORG_ID === orgId);
  }

}
```